# How can we call a method inside class in ES7?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-2016

ES6 Simple example

```
class MyClass extends SuperClass {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.myProperty = 'myProperty'
  }
}
```

In ES7, the preceding example can be written as:

```
class MyClass extends SuperClass {
  myProperty = 'myProperty'
}
```

In ES6 we can call a method inside constructor like this:

```
import myMethod from './myMethod'
class MyClass extends SuperClass {
  constructor() {
    super()
    myMethod()
  }
}
```

In ES7, How can we call a method that will be noted as constructor method?

```
import myMethod from './myMethod'
class MyClass extends SuperClass {
  myMethod()
}
```

> Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected {

---

PS: I know I can still use the ES6 syntax. But is there a way without writing constructor?

Comment: why do you expect a difference between ES6 and ES7 when it comes to retro-compatibility? what worked in ES6 works in ES7.

Comment: I don't think you can. The first "ES7" example is creating a variable. The second is calling a method, it's this that must be done within a constructor.

Comment: `PS: I know I can still use the ES6 syntax. But is there a way without writing constructor?` "ECMAScript 2016 introduced only two new features:

Array.prototype.includes() , 
Exponentiation operator" https://medium.freecodecamp.org/ecmascript-2016-es7-features-86903c5cab70 , why do you expect the feature you want to exist at first place? You are getting an error because the syntax of your last code snippet is not valid javascript, there is nothing more to it.

Comment: You are calling `myMethod()` in the class body, that is the reason of the error, there is absolutely no difference in method calling between es6 and es7

Comment: for few days back i also see a console error about `import` statements in chrome for  `{` and for `export` as well.

Comment: Furthermore, as of now ` myProperty = 'myProperty'` is not valid javascript, so you cannot write that unless you are using some transpiler like Babel. go ahead, type your second code snippet in Chrome. It will yield an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a *possible* way of achieving that without writing a constructor, but it's not something you should want to do - class fields are meant for properties that are assigned *to* the instantiated object. If it's not meant to be a property of the object, it should be done in the constructor instead.

```js
function myMethod() {
  console.log('method running');
}

class SuperClass { }
class MyClass extends SuperClass {
  someIrrelevantPropName = (myMethod(), undefined)
}
const someInstantiation = new MyClass();
```

Note that this will actually assign `undefined` to `someInstantiation.someIrrelevantPropName`. That is, `'someIrrelevantPropName' in someInstantiation` will evaluate to `true`, so this comma operator exploit is not without side-effects.

Comment: Your piece of code doesn't run without Babel enabled. This is not valid javascript as of now. It may be supported by some browsers but Chrome doesn't support that for instance. It is not in the spec. That line `someIrrelevantPropName = (myMethod(), undefined)` will yield an error without Babel enabled.

Comment: @CertainPerformance, Can you please elaborate a little bit or direct me to an article? Let me know if I'm getting it correctly. someIrrelevantPropName calls myMethod() and then set it's value to undefined?

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR - You can't, you should do it the same way as you would do in ES6.

What you do with the properties is part of the [class fields declaration proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields), method declarations like you want are not a part of that proposal.

The proposal is currently in stage 3, which means that it's not yet part of the official ECMAScript specifications, but could be coming soon (maybe in ES2019?). So I would even advise against the class properties you used in the example because the syntax of it could still change.